# Change $HOME and logout user

Tags: login, root, home-directory, logout

I wanted to change my `$HOME`, so I looked on this forum for answers. I saw a way to change `$HOME` with the code

```
sudo usermod -d /path/to/new/home -m username
```

but when I entered the code it said

```
user <username> is currently used by process 2
```

So I tried to log In to the root user. I managed that with

```
su -
```

But then it still said

```
user <username> is currently used by process 2
```

So I somehow have to log out from my normal user, while I'm loged In to the root user. So I found the code

```
sudo pkill -KILL -u <username>
```

But when I did that the shell closed.

So my problem is now, that I can't log out without closing my shell. So if anyone knows a solution to solve this problem or knows an other way for a different step, please answer

Comment: The easiest way would be to create a temp user with admin rights, log in as that user, edit your main user, log out of temp and back to main, and finally delete the temp user again.

Comment: @ByteCommander Please post that as an answer, and don't post answers in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching tty before logging in?

1. Restart your system and do not log in.
2. When presented with login, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>

   - This will bring you to a black login screen
3. Login as `root`
4. `usermod -d /path/to/new/home -m username`
5. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to return to X tty (or reboot)

   - This should bring you back to your GUI.
   - I'm pretty sure that Ubuntu puts X on tty7, but used to be tty6.
6. Login as `username`.

If you're not familiar with your `root` password, you can change it so that you are able to login as root (`sudo passwd`).